# How to increase values of polars dataframe column by index

Tags: python, numpy, python-polars

I have a data frame as follow

```
┌────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ time       ┆ open     ┆ high     ┆ low      ┆ close    │
│ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64        ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1649016000 ┆ 46405.49 ┆ 47444.11 ┆ 46248.84 ┆ 46407.35 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1649030400 ┆ 46407.36 ┆ 46461.14 ┆ 45744.77 ┆ 46005.44 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1649044800 ┆ 46005.43 ┆ 46293.38 ┆ 45834.39 ┆ 46173.99 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1649059200 ┆ 46174.0  ┆ 46287.97 ┆ 45787.0  ┆ 46160.09 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...        ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ...      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1653278400 ┆ 30171.32 ┆ 30670.51 ┆ 30101.07 ┆ 30457.01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1653292800 ┆ 30457.01 ┆ 30616.18 ┆ 30281.89 ┆ 30397.11 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1653307200 ┆ 30397.12 ┆ 30625.98 ┆ 29967.07 ┆ 30373.53 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1653321600 ┆ 30373.53 ┆ 30529.9  ┆ 30042.09 ┆ 30121.02 │
└────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

I want to count how many times each price (low and high) were local minimum/maximum in a window range of 2 to 50.

first I add two columns for count of being local min/max for each row and fill by zeros

```
raw_data["lmin_count"] = np.zeros(len(raw_data), dtype=np.int16)
raw_data["lmax_count"] = np.zeros(len(raw_data), dtype=np.int16)
```

then I iterate window length from 2 to 50 and find index of each local min/max by using:

```
for _order in range(2, 51):
    local_minima = argrelextrema(raw_data["low"].to_numpy(), np.less, order=_order)[0]
    local_maxima = argrelextrema(raw_data["high"].to_numpy(), np.greater, order=_order)[0]
```

which `order` is window length.

and in each iteration over window length I want to increase value of `lmin_count` and `lmax_count` by indices found in `local_minima` and `local_maxima`
I tried increasing value by this code:

```
if len(local_minima) > 1:
    raw_data[local_minima,5] += 1
if len(local_maxima) > 1:
    raw_data[local_minima,6] += 1
```

which `local_minima` and `local_maxima` are array of indices and `5`,`6` are index of `lmin_count` and `lmax_count` columns.

but got error `not implemented`.

So what is the best way to increase (or assign) value of column by row indices?

### Update 2022/05/24

As answers were very helpful now I have other issues.
I changed my code as follow:

```
min_expr_list = [
    (
        pl.col("price").rolling_min(
            window_size=_order * 2 + 1, min_periods=_order + 2, center=True
        )
        == pl.col("price")
    ).cast(pl.UInt32)
    for _order in range(200, 1001)
]

max_expr_list = [
    (
        pl.col("price").rolling_max(
            window_size=_order * 2 + 1, min_periods=_order + 2, center=True
        )
        == pl.col("price")
    ).cast(pl.UInt32)
    for _order in range(200, 1001)
]
raw_data = raw_data.with_columns(
    [
        pl.sum(min_expr_list).alias("min_freq"),
        pl.sum(max_expr_list).alias("max_freq"),
    ]
)
```

first: is it possible to merge both `min_expr_list` and `max_expr_list` into one list? and if it is possible, in `with_columns` expression how can I add separate columns based on each element of list?

another issue I am facing is memory usage of this approach.
In previous example `_order` were limited but in action it is more wider than example.

currently I have datasets with millions of records (some of them have more than 10 million records) and `_orders` range can be from 2 to 1500 so calculating needs lots of GB of ram.

is there any better way to do that?

and one more side problem. when increasing `_order` to more than 1000 it seems it doesn't work. is there any limitation in source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if we can build on @ritchie46 response and nudge you closer to the finish line.

##### Data

I've concatenated the 'open', 'high', and 'low' columns in your sample data, just to give us some data to work with.  I've also added a `row_nr` column, just for discussion.  (It won't be used in any calculations whatsoever, so you don't need to include it in your final code.)

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [
            46405.49, 46407.36, 46005.43, 46174.00, 30171.32, 30457.01, 30397.12, 30373.53,
            47444.11, 46461.14, 46293.38, 46287.97, 30670.51, 30616.18, 30625.98, 30529.90,
            46248.84, 45744.77, 45834.39, 45787.00, 30101.07, 30281.89, 29967.07, 30042.09,
        ]
    }
).with_row_count()
df
```

```
shape: (24, 2)
┌────────┬──────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ col1     │
│ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ u32    ┆ f64      │
╞════════╪══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 46405.49 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 46407.36 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 46005.43 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 46174.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 30171.32 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 30457.01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ 30397.12 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ 30373.53 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8      ┆ 47444.11 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9      ┆ 46461.14 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10     ┆ 46293.38 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 11     ┆ 46287.97 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 12     ┆ 30670.51 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13     ┆ 30616.18 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 14     ┆ 30625.98 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15     ┆ 30529.9  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 16     ┆ 46248.84 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 17     ┆ 45744.77 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 18     ┆ 45834.39 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 19     ┆ 45787.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 20     ┆ 30101.07 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 21     ┆ 30281.89 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 22     ┆ 29967.07 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 23     ┆ 30042.09 │
└────────┴──────────┘
```

Now, let's run the `scipy.signal.argrelextrema` code on this data.

```py
for _order in range(1, 7):
    print(
        "order:", _order, ":", argrelextrema(df["col1"].to_numpy(), np.less, order=_order)
    )
```

```
order: 1 : (array([ 2,  4,  7, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22]),)
order: 2 : (array([ 4,  7, 15, 22]),)
order: 3 : (array([ 4, 15, 22]),)
order: 4 : (array([ 4, 15, 22]),)
order: 5 : (array([ 4, 22]),)
order: 6 : (array([ 4, 22]),)
```

From the output, it looks like you're trying to find the **index** of any row that is the minimum value of a window centered on that row, for various window sizes.

For example, `row_nr` 2 is a local minimum of a window of size 3, centered on `row_nr` 2.  (Here, `order=1` in the call to `argrelextrema` means "including one value above and below", and hence "window size" = (order * 2) + 1) = 3.

Let's replicate this in Polars.  We'll take it in steps.

##### `rolling_min`

First, let's use the [`rolling_min`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.rolling_min.html) expression to calculate rolling minimums corresponding to `order` from 1 to 6.  Notice that Polars allows us to generate a list of expressions outside of the `with_columns` context.  (This often helps keep code more readable.)

I'm converting the scipy `order` keyword to the equivalent `window_size` for `rolling_min`.  Also, I'm setting the `min_periods` to make sure that there is at least *one* value on each side of the center value of any window (to replicate the scipy calculations).

```py
expr_list = [
        pl.col("col1").rolling_min(
            window_size=_order * 2 + 1,
            min_periods=_order + 2,
            center=True
        ).alias("roll_min" + str(_order))
    for _order in range(1, 7)
]
df.with_columns(expr_list)
```

```
shape: (24, 8)
┌────────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ col1     ┆ roll_min1 ┆ roll_min2 ┆ roll_min3 ┆ roll_min4 ┆ roll_min5 ┆ roll_min6 │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ u32    ┆ f64      ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 46405.49 ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 46407.36 ┆ 46005.43  ┆ 46005.43  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 46005.43 ┆ 46005.43  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 46174.0  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 30171.32 ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 30457.01 ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ 30397.12 ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ 30373.53 ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8      ┆ 47444.11 ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9      ┆ 46461.14 ┆ 46293.38  ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30171.32  ┆ 30171.32  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10     ┆ 46293.38 ┆ 46287.97  ┆ 30670.51  ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30171.32  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 11     ┆ 46287.97 ┆ 30670.51  ┆ 30616.18  ┆ 30616.18  ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30373.53  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 12     ┆ 30670.51 ┆ 30616.18  ┆ 30616.18  ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30373.53  ┆ 30373.53  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13     ┆ 30616.18 ┆ 30616.18  ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30373.53  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 14     ┆ 30625.98 ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30101.07  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15     ┆ 30529.9  ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30101.07  ┆ 30101.07  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 16     ┆ 46248.84 ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30101.07  ┆ 30101.07  ┆ 29967.07  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 17     ┆ 45744.77 ┆ 45744.77  ┆ 30529.9   ┆ 30101.07  ┆ 30101.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 18     ┆ 45834.39 ┆ 45744.77  ┆ 30101.07  ┆ 30101.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 19     ┆ 45787.0  ┆ 30101.07  ┆ 30101.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 20     ┆ 30101.07 ┆ 30101.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 21     ┆ 30281.89 ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 22     ┆ 29967.07 ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  ┆ 29967.07  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 23     ┆ 30042.09 ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
└────────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Looking at the output in `roll_min_1` (the equivalent of an `order=1` call for `argrelextrema`), we see that the values in `roll_min_1`  equal the values in `col1` for `row_nr` 2,  4,  7, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22 ... which corresponds exactly to the output of `argrelextrema` for `order=1`.  Likewise, for the other `roll_min_X` columns.  We'll use this fact in the next step.

##### Obtaining the row index

As @ritchie46 points out, in Polars, we use **conditions** (not indexing).  We'll modify the above code to identify whether the value in `col1` equals it's rolling min, for each of our window sizes.

```py
expr_list = [
    (
        pl.col("col1").rolling_min(
            window_size=_order * 2 + 1,
            min_periods=_order + 2,
            center=True
        )
        == pl.col("col1")
    ).alias("min_idx_" + str(_order))
    for _order in range(1, 7)
]
df.with_columns(expr_list)
```

```
shape: (24, 8)
┌────────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ col1     ┆ min_idx_1 ┆ min_idx_2 ┆ min_idx_3 ┆ min_idx_4 ┆ min_idx_5 ┆ min_idx_6 │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ u32    ┆ f64      ┆ bool      ┆ bool      ┆ bool      ┆ bool      ┆ bool      ┆ bool      │
╞════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 46405.49 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 46407.36 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 46005.43 ┆ true      ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 46174.0  ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 30171.32 ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 30457.01 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ 30397.12 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ 30373.53 ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8      ┆ 47444.11 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9      ┆ 46461.14 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10     ┆ 46293.38 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 11     ┆ 46287.97 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 12     ┆ 30670.51 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13     ┆ 30616.18 ┆ true      ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 14     ┆ 30625.98 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15     ┆ 30529.9  ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 16     ┆ 46248.84 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 17     ┆ 45744.77 ┆ true      ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 18     ┆ 45834.39 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 19     ┆ 45787.0  ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 20     ┆ 30101.07 ┆ true      ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 21     ┆ 30281.89 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 22     ┆ 29967.07 ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ true      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 23     ┆ 30042.09 ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     ┆ false     │
└────────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Notice that for `min_idx_1`, the values are true for `row_nr` 2,  4,  7, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, which corresponds to the output of `argrelextrema` for `order=1`.  Likewise, for the other columns.

##### Summing

We can now use the [`cast`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.cast.html) function and the [`polars.sum`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.sum.html) function to sum row-wise across our columns.  (Indeed, we won't keep our rolling min columns -- we'll just keep the sums).

```py
expr_list = [
    (
        pl.col("col1").rolling_min(
            window_size=_order * 2 + 1,
            min_periods=_order + 2,
            center=True
        )
        == pl.col("col1")
    ).cast(pl.UInt32)
    for _order in range(1, 7)
]
df.with_columns(pl.sum(expr_list).alias("min_freq"))
```

```
┌────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ col1     ┆ min_freq │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ u32    ┆ f64      ┆ u32      │
╞════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 46405.49 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 46407.36 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 46005.43 ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 46174.0  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 30171.32 ┆ 6        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 30457.01 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ 30397.12 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ 30373.53 ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8      ┆ 47444.11 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9      ┆ 46461.14 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10     ┆ 46293.38 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 11     ┆ 46287.97 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 12     ┆ 30670.51 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13     ┆ 30616.18 ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 14     ┆ 30625.98 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15     ┆ 30529.9  ┆ 4        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 16     ┆ 46248.84 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 17     ┆ 45744.77 ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 18     ┆ 45834.39 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 19     ┆ 45787.0  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 20     ┆ 30101.07 ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 21     ┆ 30281.89 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 22     ┆ 29967.07 ┆ 6        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 23     ┆ 30042.09 ┆ 0        │
└────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

I believe this is the result you were looking to obtain.

From here, I think you can expand the above code for rolling maximums.

##### Ties

One difference between this code and the `argrelextrema` code pertains to ties.  If two values tie for the minimum in any window, `argrelextrema` considers **neither** to be the minimum for the window.  The code above considers **both** to be minimum values.

I'm not sure how likely this will be for the size of windows you have, or for the type of data.

##### Please update Polars to `0.13.38`

The latest release of Polars contains some **major** improvements to the performance of rolling functions.  (The announcement is on this [Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/RitchieVink/status/1528671911542149121).)  You'll want to take advantage of that by updating to the latest version.

### Update - 2022/05/24

##### Merging all lists into one expression

> first: is it possible to merge both min_expr_list and max_expr_list into one list? and if it is possible, in with_columns expression how can I add separate columns based on each element of list?

It is possible to generate all columns (min and max, for each order, for each variable) using a single list in a single `with_columns` context.  The calculations are independent, and thus can be in the same `with_columns` context.  Each column would have a name that could be used in a later calculation step.

But in that case, the accumulation steps would need to be in a separate `with_columns` expression.  The `with_columns` context assumes all calculations are independent - and that they can be run in any order, without dependencies.  But summarizing columns (by selecting them by name) is dependent on those columns first being created.

You can return multiple Series from a single function if you return them as a Series of `struct` (e.g., using `map`) .. but that's generally to be avoided.  (And beyond the scope of our question here.)

And more specifically for this problem, we are dealing with issues of memory pressure.  So, in this case, we'll need to move in the opposite direction - we'll need to break lists into smaller pieces and feed them to the `with_columns` expression in batches.

##### Batching the calculations by `order`

> currently I have datasets with millions of records (some of them have more than 10 million records) and _orders range can be from 2 to 1500 so calculating needs lots of GB of ram.
> is there any better way to do that?

We'll try a couple of techniques to reduce memory pressure ... and still achieve good performance.

One technique will be to use the [`fold`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.fold.html) method to accumulate values.  This allows us to sum boolean values without having to cast every intermediate column to integers.  This should reduce memory pressure during the intermediate calculations.

We'll also batch our calculations by breaking the expression lists into sub-lists, calculating intermediate results, and accumulating into an accumulator column using the `fold` method.

First, let's eliminate the `cast` to integer in your `min_expr_list`.

```py
min_expr_list = [
    (
        pl.col("price").rolling_min(
            window_size=_order * 2 + 1, min_periods=_order + 2, center=True
        )
        == pl.col("price")
    )
    for _order in range(1, 20)
]
```

Next we'll need to pick a `batch_size` and initialize an accumulator column.  I would experiment with different `batch_size` numbers until you find one that seems to work well for your computing platform and size of dataset.  Since we have limited data in this example, I'll pick a `batch_size` of 5 - just to demonstrate the algorithm.

```py
batch_size = 5
df = df.with_column(pl.lit(0, dtype=pl.UInt32).alias("min_freq"))
```

Next, we'll iterate through the batches of sub-lists, and accumulate as we go.

```py
while(min_expr_list):
    next_batch, min_expr_list = min_expr_list[0: batch_size], min_expr_list[batch_size:]
    df=(
        df
        .with_column(
            pl.fold(
                pl.col("min_freq"),
                lambda acc, x: acc + x,
                next_batch,
            )
        )
    )

print(df)
```

```
shape: (24, 3)
┌────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ price    ┆ min_freq │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ u32    ┆ f64      ┆ u32      │
╞════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 46405.49 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 46407.36 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 46005.43 ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 46174.0  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 30171.32 ┆ 15       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 30457.01 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6      ┆ 30397.12 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ 30373.53 ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8      ┆ 47444.11 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9      ┆ 46461.14 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10     ┆ 46293.38 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 11     ┆ 46287.97 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 12     ┆ 30670.51 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13     ┆ 30616.18 ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 14     ┆ 30625.98 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15     ┆ 30529.9  ┆ 4        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 16     ┆ 46248.84 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 17     ┆ 45744.77 ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 18     ┆ 45834.39 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 19     ┆ 45787.0  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 20     ┆ 30101.07 ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 21     ┆ 30281.89 ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 22     ┆ 29967.07 ┆ 19       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 23     ┆ 30042.09 ┆ 0        │
└────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

##### Problems with `rolling_min` when `order` is 1,000 or more

> and one more side problem. when increasing _order to more than 1000 it seems it doesn't work. is there any limitation in source code?

I generated datasets of 50 million random numbers and tested the `rolling_min` for order sizes of 1,500 .. and found no problems.  Indeed, I replicated the algorithm using a rolling `slice` and found no errors.

But I have a hunch about what might be happening.  Let's start with this dataset of 10 records:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (10, 1)
┌──────┐
│ col1 │
│ ---  │
│ i64  │
╞══════╡
│ 1    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10   │
└──────┘
```

If we set `_order = 8` and run the algorithm, we get a result.

```py
_order = 8
df = df.with_column(
    pl.col("col1")
    .rolling_min(window_size=(2 * _order) + 1, min_periods=(_order + 2), center=True)
    .alias("rolling_min")
)
df
```

```
shape: (10, 2)
┌──────┬─────────────┐
│ col1 ┆ rolling_min │
│ ---  ┆ ---         │
│ i64  ┆ i64         │
╞══════╪═════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 1           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ 1           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ 1           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5    ┆ 1           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6    ┆ 1           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7    ┆ 1           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8    ┆ 1           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9    ┆ 1           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10   ┆ null        │
└──────┴─────────────┘
```

However, if we set `_order=9`, we get all null values:

```
shape: (10, 2)
┌──────┬─────────────┐
│ col1 ┆ rolling_min │
│ ---  ┆ ---         │
│ i64  ┆ i64         │
╞══════╪═════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5    ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6    ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7    ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8    ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9    ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10   ┆ null        │
└──────┴─────────────┘
```

Is this what you're seeing?  The reason for the `null` values is the `min_period` value.  We set `min_period = _order + 2`, which in this case is 11.  However, there are only 10 values in the dataset.  Thus, we get all `null` values.

Perhaps this is what is happening in your data?

Comment: thank you @cbilot for great answer
just one more thing about the way you calculated freq in rolling_min
if I want to calculate by both rolling_min and rolling_max can I do it in one expression and and them to original datafram using ```with_columns```? if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

You write very imperative code which is not really idiomatic polars. You typically should not even know where the index of a value is. Instead you assign by `conditions`, for instance with `when(condition) -> then(value) -> otherwise(value)` expressions.

Your condition in a `when` can still refer to an index. This snippet for instance is equal to assigning to a specific index, but then written more functional:

```py
pl.DataFrame({
    "letters": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
}).with_column(
    # use a condition to determine the index location
    pl.when(pl.arange(0, pl.count()) == 2)
      .then("idx_2")
      .otherwise("letters").alias("letters")
)
```

```
shape: (4, 1)
┌─────────┐
│ letters │
│ ---     │
│ str     │
╞═════════╡
│ letters │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ letters │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ idx_2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ letters │
└─────────┘
```

## Your intent, counting local minima/maxima

To help you in your cause, I'd like to show how you can find your local minima in an idiomatic polars way.

The local minima/maxima can be found by:

- taking the derivative `dy/dx` of a function `x`.
- computing the `sign` of that derivative tells us where the functions slope is increasing and decreasing.
- if we take the derivative of the sign of `dy/dx` we know where the signs are changing and thus where we have local minima/maxima.

Let's try this on a dummy `DataFrame`.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "x": [8, 4, 2, 7, 9, 6, 3, 0]
})

# find the local minima/maxima
df = df.with_columns([
    (pl.col("x").diff().sign().diff().shift(-1) == -2).alias("local_maximum"),
    (pl.col("x").diff().sign().diff().shift(-1) == 2).alias("local_minimum")
])
print(df)
```

```
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬───────────────┬───────────────┐
│ x   ┆ local_maximum ┆ local_minimum │
│ --- ┆ ---           ┆ ---           │
│ i64 ┆ bool          ┆ bool          │
╞═════╪═══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 8   ┆ false         ┆ false         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ false         ┆ false         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ false         ┆ true          │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7   ┆ false         ┆ false         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9   ┆ true          ┆ false         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6   ┆ false         ┆ false         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ false         ┆ false         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ false         ┆ false         │
└─────┴───────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Next we can take the `cumulative sum` to count the total seen local minima and maxima.

```py
df.with_columns([
    pl.col("local_maximum").cumsum().alias("local_max_count"),
    pl.col("local_minimum").cumsum().alias("local_min_count")
])
```

```
shape: (8, 5)
┌─────┬───────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ x   ┆ local_maximum ┆ local_minimum ┆ local_max_count ┆ local_min_count │
│ --- ┆ ---           ┆ ---           ┆ ---             ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ bool          ┆ bool          ┆ u32             ┆ u32             │
╞═════╪═══════════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 8   ┆ false         ┆ false         ┆ 0               ┆ 0               │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ false         ┆ false         ┆ 0               ┆ 0               │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ false         ┆ true          ┆ 0               ┆ 1               │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7   ┆ false         ┆ false         ┆ 0               ┆ 1               │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9   ┆ true          ┆ false         ┆ 1               ┆ 1               │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6   ┆ false         ┆ false         ┆ 1               ┆ 1               │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ false         ┆ false         ┆ 1               ┆ 1               │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ false         ┆ false         ┆ 1               ┆ 1               │
└─────┴───────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

I hope this helps nudge you in the right direction.